# How to test a custom controller

Tags: unit-test, custom-controller

I have a controller that takes a contact ID from a page, makes some database queries to set up some info for the page. I just can't see how to go about setting up a test class. Its my first attempt at testing a controller.

What I need is a way to set the contact ID. At the moment it fails at
if (county == null) {county = String.valueOf(contactInfo[0].Home_County__c); }
I think because there is nothing being returned from database query.
error is System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

==Controller==

```
public FindNearby () {

    conID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); //gets ID from page

    System.debug(conID);

    if(conID == null){ //used during testing, shouldn't be needed once deployed

        conID = '0031100000muP4NAAU';
    }


        //sets the record ID for schools
        SchoolID = [SELECT ID FROM RecordType where sObjectType='Account' and DeveloperName='School'].id;
        //grabs info on Volunteer from database
        contactInfo = [SELECT Are_you_an_Engineer__c, Best_described__c, 
                       Preferred_Counties_for_Volunteering__c, Home_County__c 
                       FROM Contact WHERE Id = :conID];
        //sets county to Home if none selected
        if (county == null) {county = String.valueOf(contactInfo[0].Home_County__c); }

        //Database query, finds all schools which are mapped and visits that are open 
        //If some form of Engineer is selected finds all Engineer based visits otherwise finds everything else

        if((contactInfo[0].Are_you_an_Engineer__c != 'No')&&(contactInfo[0].Are_you_an_Engineer__c != null)) {

            schoolQuery = [SELECT Lat__c, Lng__c, ID, Name, County__c,
            (SELECT School__c, ID,Topic__c, Date__c, Class_Year__c, Requires_Irish_speaker__c, Preferred_Time__c 
            FROM School_Visits__r WHERE Status__c LIKE 'Open%' AND Topic__c in :visitTypes )
            FROM Account WHERE RecordType.ID = :SchoolID AND isMapped__c = true];

           } else {

            schoolQuery = [SELECT Lat__c, Lng__c, ID, Name, County__c,
            (SELECT School__c, ID,Topic__c, Date__c, Class_Year__c, Requires_Irish_speaker__c, Preferred_Time__c 
            FROM School_Visits__r WHERE Status__c LIKE 'Open%' AND Topic__c not in :visitTypes )
            FROM Account WHERE RecordType.ID = :SchoolID AND isMapped__c = true];

           }       

        prepareVisitInfo(); //method to prepare visit and school info to pass to javascript

}
```

==Test Class==

```
    @isTest
public class ToTestFindNearby {

    static testMethod void testFindNearby () {

        PageReference pageRef = Page.FindNearby; 

        Contact contact = new Contact (LastName = 'Test', Are_you_an_Engineer__c = 'No', Home_County__c = 'Waterford' );
        Account school = new Account (Name = 'Test', County__c = 'Waterford', Lat__c=5.0000, Lng__c=10.000);
         //Test.startTest();
        insert contact;
        insert school; 

        school = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE id = :school.id];       
        School_Visit__c schoolVisit = new School_Visit__c(School__c = school.ID, Status__c = 'Open for Volunteering', Topic__c = 'Science');
        insert schoolVisit;
       // Test.stopTest();

        contact = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE id = :contact.id];

        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        FindNearby controller = new FindNearby();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not far off - just add the id to the params of the pageRef

```
@isTest
public class ToTestFindNearby {

static testMethod void testFindNearby () {

    PageReference pageRef = Page.FindNearby; 

    Contact contact = new Contact (LastName = 'Test', Are_you_an_Engineer__c = 'No', Home_County__c = 'Waterford' );
    Account school = new Account (Name = 'Test', County__c = 'Waterford', Lat__c=5.0000, Lng__c=10.000);
     //Test.startTest();
    insert contact;
    insert school; 

//don't need to do this as SFDC will populate the id for you.
//    school = [SELECT ID FROM Account WHERE id = :school.id];       
    School_Visit__c schoolVisit = new School_Visit__c(School__c = school.ID, Status__c = 'Open for Volunteering', Topic__c = 'Science');
    insert schoolVisit;
   // Test.stopTest();

//don't need this bit either
    contact = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE id = :contact.id];

pageRef.getParameters().put('id', contact.id);
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    FindNearby controller = new FindNearby();

}
}
```